# jQuery Toggle(); was working, now not

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, toggle

I can see this question has been asked many times before, but no suggested solution seems to work for my issues with Toggle();

Context: I have some 'Tips' for that page (`div.tips`). On a mobile device, I want the user to be able to click a button called Tips (`button.tips`), and have the content pop up under the button. They can then click the button and the content will disappear again.

I'm using Toggle on the mobile version of a site, I'm getting the width of the window using these two lines:

```
var windowsize = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
});
```

So, I have two instances where I need to move things around for the mobile site, so I'm using appendTo() to accomplish this. Here's problem code number 1:

```
$("div.results").hide();

$("div.result-summary").click(function () {
        $("div.result-summary").hasClass("active-result");
        $("div.result-summary").removeClass("active-result");

        $(this).toggleClass("active-result");

        if (windowsize < 1015) {
            $("div.results").appendTo(this);
            $("div.results").toggle();
        } else {
            $("div.results").show();
        }
});
```

The first part works fine, so jQuery is being loaded. It's the `if (windowsize < 1015) {` part that gets no reaction from the browser at all. Also, I have no errors in the console.

Problem code number 2 is much the same:

```
if (windowsize < 1015) {
        $("div.tips").hide();
                    $("div.tips").appendTo("div.append");

        $('button.tips').click(function(){
            $("div.tips").toggle();
        });
}
```

Again, nothing happens in the browser and I get no console errors.

I have a feeling the issue is with the `windowsize < 1015` line, but this used to work before, and now doesn't, so I'm not sure what's up!

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Scoping issue on windowsize variable. You are never updating the global variable on resize, instead you're updating a local var then letting it get trashed by the GC

Comment: While the scoping issue was the cause `.toggle()` is deprecated from 1.8. So I would avoid using it unless you really have to and you really don't.

Comment: Toggle has been depreciated?? Really?

Comment: @lucas572 No, it has not been depreciated for showing and hiding elements, it was depreciated for binding a click event. Your current use-case is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scoping issue on `windowsize` variable. You are never updating the global variable on resize, instead you're updating a local var then letting it get trashed by the GC

```
var windowsize = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
    windowsize = $(window).width();
});
```

It should have never worked (properly) like you had it.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I didn't spot that myself! BUT, still not working after the change, hmm :S

Comment: What isn't working about it? are you not getting inside the if statement at all? (add a console log inside of it)

Comment: The content is being appended to the correct place, however it's stil `display: none`, the `toggle` isn't toggling the show/hide of the div for some reason.

Comment: I don't know what the context is around your if statment, but it doesn't make much sense as it is now to bind a click event inside of it. Updating that variable won't magically make the if statement run again just because it changed, and that also won't unbind it when the var is no longer less than x

Comment: I have some 'Tips' for that page (`div.tips`). On a mobile device, I want the user to be able to click a button called Tips (`button.tips`), and have the content pop up under the button. They can then click the button and the content will disappear again.

Comment: What is it currently doing?

Comment: It is appending the div to the `div.append`, it's just not toggling from `display: none` to `display: block`

Comment: Ok, all of that works. http://jsfiddle.net/RgUHz/ Add an alert or console log to the click event to see if it's being triggered.

Comment: Ah! I added a console log and I get two clicks come through, instead of one! So it's displaying/hiding instantly :S

Comment: Yup, logic issue, probably related to the context of where that if statement is located relative to the event binding. The event binding is happening twice.

Answer (score 0):

Although the first answer did solve an issue. The reason the Toggle wasn't working (and I find this strange, because everything was) is that WordPress (the platform I'm building on) doesn't like using `$` in the code.

I had originally fixed this by using the suggested `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

However, once I changed this to: `(function($) {` and closed it off with `})(jQuery);` everything worked!